# Can I log Simulated Instrument time with a safety pilot if I need an Instrument Proficiency Check?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-procedures, instrument-rating, safety-pilot

**Can I log  Simulated Instrument flight time and instrument approaches with a safety pilot if I need an Instrument Proficiency Check?**

I am instrument rated but haven't done my 6 Instrument approaches in over 12 months. So I can not file IFR on my own. Can I bring up an instrument-rated safety pilot 'who is not a CFI/CFII' while I sit left seat with foggles on during VFR conditions and shoot approaches? Can I log it as Simulated Instrument flight time and Instrument approaches even if I need an Instrument Proficiency Check?

Comment: Are you asking if you can merely record the simulated instrument time and approaches in your logbook even though the time and approaches would not count towards instrument currency since you now need an IPC?

Comment: Yes, can you still log the time even though it will not count toward recurrency?

Comment: It's your logbook so you can write anything in it you wish. For example, if you took a blimp ride and wanted to memorialize the the time you could put it in your logbook. It's the time in your logbook that you offer up as meeting some FAR requirement for a certificate, rating, currency etc., (logged in accordance with 61.51) that counts. So, if you comingle time in your logbook that doesn't count towards anything, with time you want to use to meet some FAR requirement you should have some way of making that distinction clear.

Comment: Will it count toward my simulated IMC column?

Comment: If, in the future, you apply for a certificate or rating that requires a certain amount of instrument flight time your simulated instrument time with a safety pilot (see FAR 91.109 (c) could be used if acquired in accordance with the FAR's and logged in accordance with FAR 61.51. For example, see FAR 61.159 (a)(4) regarding meeting requirements for an ATP cert.

Comment: I edited your question a bit for readability by those who may be unfamiliar with some of your abbreviations.  If it does not read the way you intended please modify it as necessary.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help 

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing stopping *any* pilot from shooting a VFR practice approach under the hood with a qualified safety pilot.  And if you do it properly (hood on until minimums), you can log it.

However, if you are already past the grace period, you still must get an IPC before you can file IFR, and that will reset the currency timer anyway.

So, while these practice approaches may help you maintain (or regain) proficiency before doing the IPC, and you may find it personally useful to have a record of that, it has no legal effect on your currency.